# How to validate a field with respect to other field?

Tags: antd

I'm trying to input restaurant opening/closing times with Ant design. Here's my code so far:

```
              <Col>
                <Form.Item
                  label={<p style={{ color: "white" }}>Open</p>}
                  name="opening_time"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please input a valid opening time",
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <TimePicker />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Item
                  label={<p style={{ color: "white" }}>Close</p>}
                  name="closing_time"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "Please input a valid closing time",
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <TimePicker />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
```

How can I add a validation rule that forces `closing_time > opening_time`. I understand a custom validator is required inside the `rules` section of closing_time input field but how to reference the value of `opening_time`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Form-Hook:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

Then it is always possible to access the present value of another `Form.Item` using `form.getFieldValue(...)` and the name of your `Form.Item`.

So you are right then, you need a specific `validate` function inside the rules array. Here you can get the value of all fields like I explained above.

e.g.

```
...
<Form.Item
  label={<p style={{ color: "white" }}>Close</p>}
  name="closing_time"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Please input a valid closing time",
    },
    ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
      validator(_, value) {
        if (!value) {
          return Promise.resolve();
        }

        const opening_time = getFieldValue("opening_time");

        //check if opening time is before closing time
        if (opening_time < value) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Error!'));
        }

      },
    })
  ]}
>
  <TimePicker />
</Form.Item>
...
```